# Magento API catalog_product.info get all products

Tags: api, magento

I want to get info about all product info from all products using catalog_product.info. So i tired excluding the product id argument from the catalog_product.info call

```
$result = $client->call($session, 'catalog_product.info');
```

That didn't work

so i tired to filter like in the catalog_product.list call for all simple products

```
$productId =array('type' => array('is' => 'simple'));
$result = $client->call($session, 'catalog_product.info', $productId);
```

i got an error "SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined"

So my questions is
1) Can catalog_product.info get all products?
2) Can we filter catalog_product.info for simple products only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) No, **catalog_product.info** allows retrieve information only about the required product,

2) Yes, You can filter all simple products but with **catalog_product.list** method:

```
$params = array(array(
        'type' =>
          array(
            'in' => 'simple'
               )
          ));



$result = $client->call($session, 'catalog_product.list', $params);
```

Comment: I just learning API, how can i use the above code, could you kindly explain all steps.